# Not dereferencing produces a warning when compiling

Tags: c

I'm struggling to understand the nuances of char arrays and string literals, and I'm quite confused as to why the following code produces a warning when I compile it.

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[4]’ [-Wformat=]
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char str_arr[4] = "abc";
    char (*p)[4];
    p = &str_arr;
    printf("A single character: %c\n",(*p)[1]);  
    printf("The entire string: %s\n",p); // When I replace p with *p, the warning goes away, why?
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly, `p` is a pointer to a char array of size 4 and after assigning it, it now points to the char array `str_array`. If we dereference `p` that gives us the entire char array, but doesn't `%s` require a `char*` as an argument? If we have a char array in place of a char pointer in the argument, shouldn't that produce a warning?

Comment: With `char str_arr[3] = "abc";` there's no space for the null-terminator. You can't use this array as a string.

Comment: Please include the warning in your question (copy-and-paste it, and format it as code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `%s` expects an argument of type `char *`. The type of `p` is not `char *`. But when you dereference `p`, with `*p`, you get an array of `char` that will *decay* to `char *`.

Some compilers are able to detect format-string and argument mismatch and warn about it, because it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: My question then is, will an array always decay to a pointer when it is used in an argument that requires a pointer?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, it's well-defined. Arrays decays to pointers to their first elements. So for `str_arr` it will decay to `&str_arr[0]`.

Comment: @Anthony Array always decay except for `&a` and `sizeof(a)` (and anything similar to `sizeof` that might exist)

Comment: @ikegami Intuitively, it doesn't make sense to me how &a refers to the memory address of the entire array. Would it not make sense for &a to decay into &a[0]?

Comment: @Anthony heh? If `a` decayed in `&a`, that would make `&a` equivalent to `&(&a[0])`, and that's garbage. It's doesn't even compile, since can't get the address of something that's not an object.

Comment: @ikegami I see. But just to clarify, &a refers to the memory address of the entire array, correct? At least, that it what I was taught.

Comment: @Anthony I recommend you think of the `&` operator as the *pointer-to* operator. For any variable `a`, then `&a` is a "pointer to `a`". If `a` is an array, then `&a` a pointer to the array itself, not any individual element.

Comment: @Anthony, `&o` returns a pointer to `o` (no matter what kind of object `o` is). I don't know what you mean by "entire".

Comment: @Anthony This is all about C having stricter type safety for pointers than for plain variables. But since what's actually stored at address `p` is not just the array, but also the first item, you could also in this specific case safely cast to `(char*)p` (pointer to the first item) and that would have worked too.